# Selenium define constant Variable to be shared over Multi-test

Tags: java, variables, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to share a constant variable over multi-tests in selenium 
For example `String text = "the shared text over tests";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your class of constants like this:

```
public class Constants {
// now here you can define your constant variables 
public static text = "the shared text over tests";
}
```

now, you can use your constant variable in any class of your package like this:

```
String constantText = Constants.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define it a class containing all your shared stuff:

```
public class TestConstants {
  public static final String SHARED_TEXT = "My shared text";
}
```

and then in your tests you can simply reference it as:

```
TestConstants.SHARED_TEXT.equals(actualText);
```

or however you need it to